# How to restore a deleted google console project

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-messaging, google-oauth, google-api-console

Twenty days ago I deleted a [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0) project.  However I forgot that it's was / linked to an android application for GCM notification. I can't even see the deleted projects from my console.

I have about 1M users registered and I can't send push notifications. I have tried to send push notifications but they failed for all my applications.

Can anyone help me to restore my project or at least is it possible to send push notifications even the project with `SENDER_ID` and `API_KEY` (old implementation) had been deleted?

Comment: What was your old SENDER_ID?

Comment: SENDER_ID = "568197537469"

Comment: You received an email from Google that clearly stated "project will be inaccessible and can no longer be undeleted."    The answer is you cant. Its gone.

Comment: Was the API_KEY hardcoded on devices? If you were using it only server-side you may simply be able to create a new project and register your Android app in it. Make sure you name it identically to your Android app so you know not to delete it.

Comment: @DalmTo ,so no way to message those 1M users!

Comment: @breno,The API_KEY is only server-side,I don't know if gcm still works with (SENDER_ID,API_KEY) !

Comment: You can undelete the project yourself for 7 days (documented: https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/ ).  After that time it is not possible for you to undelete. 

You could try contacting developer support to see if they can help you restore the deleted data: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/dev_registration  be sure to include your sender_id so they can look up your project.

Comment: Thanks god for that @WilliamDenniss, you just saved me and my project from having to deploy a new version just because I was stupid enough to delete a project I shouldn't...